# Controller and controller action not working after project name in Url

Tags: php, yii2

I want url like localhost/projec_name/controller/controllerAction in yii2. But getting **Object not found!** screen if I use **localhost/advanced/site/about in url (this controller and action is not deleted)**.

can you Guys please check the code? what I am doing wrong?

.htaccess in folder frontend/

[image]

.htaccess in folder advanced/ (root)

[image]

frontend/config/main.php

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it what I was doing wrong.
I have added .htaccess file in folder frontend/
and now I have moved it in frontend/web and error is gone. :)